# ! meaning in c++ (following context)

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I know what != is when if(x!=value){...}, but what does it mean in the following context:

```
 if (! ReadConsoleInput(
                hStdin,      // input buffer handle
                irInBuf,     // buffer to read into
                128,         // size of read buffer
                &cNumRead) ) // number of records read
            ErrorExit("ReadConsoleInput");
```

or

```
if (! SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwMode) )
        ErrorExit("SetConsoleMode");
```

or

```
 if (! GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &fdwSaveOldMode) )
        ErrorExit("GetConsoleMode");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the "Not" operator: true (1) if the operand is zero, false (0) otherwise.

Comment: So control will reach if(..){//whatevers here}                     if GetConsoleMode(...) returns 0

Comment: @someguy: Confused by what you mean, but it's basically `if (!SUCCESS) { ... }`

Comment: so control will reach whatever is in the if statement if GetConsoleMode(...) = 0

Comment: @Mehrdad: "true (1) if..., false(0) otherwise" - this implies `true` *is* `1` and `false` *is* `0`, but those boolean values are just allowed to be implicitly converted to those numbers in an integral context.  I think this should be reworded.

Comment: @Tony: I was kind of hand-waving there, since for practical purposes I don't really think the exact wording of the standard matters here.

Comment: So control will reach "whatever is here" in the following ex code:                                                                   void foo(){return false;)  if (!foo()){//whatever's here}

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm making buttons in my game and I'm trying to understand the code sample I got from MSDN

Comment: @someguy: If you're also learning programming in the process, I recommend you grab a book and learn a language like Java or C#, and *then* start writing games. :) As great as learning by example is, learning from a book helps a lot.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty far into c++. I can do a lot of things, that was just one concept I was confused on. But is C# better for games

Comment: @someguy: Yes and no, it depends. Notice, though, that I did *not* mention C++ as a starting point -- it's pretty much the worst language to start at, IMO, and it causes too much needless confusion (it certainly did for me and others I know).

Comment: Oh Well, I have started with c++ and it is probably taking me longer to learn than it would if I learned c first, but I know it pretty well or as far as I know. But what does C# or VB or Java have that c++ doesn't

Comment: @someguy: Question marks would be appreciated. :P It's actually the fact that they *don't* have a lot of things that makes them better -- they're easier to learn, especially Java, but still powerful.

Comment: @someguy: I think I can't explain this well, and unfortunately the most convincing way is that you actually learn both and see what I mean. :\ (And thanks for the question marks, I think that more than makes up for their lack thereof previously...)

Comment: So now that I've started, will it be hard to transition or should I just stick with C++

Comment: @someguy: Hm... have you learned about (1) templates, (2) pointers, (3) operator overloading?

Comment: Just wondering. Which real world apps are coded in c++ and which are coded in java. (Any type of software)

Comment: Yes I have. I also know classes pretty well, member functions, and a little streaming i/o with files.

Comment: Yes I have. I also know classes pretty well, member functions, and a little streaming i/o with files.

Comment: @someguy: In that case, it's probably not worth stopping and learning something else, just go on learning C++. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

`!` is LOGICAL NOT, i.e.: `if (! boolVar)` equals to `if (true != boolVar)`, and `if (! intVar)` equals to `if (0 == intVar)`

If you have a function `foo()` that returns 0 on error, checking `if (! foo())` is basically checking if the function succeeded or not, enter brackets on failure.

You have, of course, to know exactly the return values policy for each function, there's no law or rule about it.

Comment: @littleadv: `if (!intvar)` equals to `if (0 != intvar)`... nope... it's `if (0 == intvar)`.  More generally, this is true for the bool and int types listed because of their implicit conversion to bool to allow `!` to operate, but this conception of substituting a value and `==` or `!=` need not hold for classes with conversion operators... I don't think it's a helpful model for understanding `!`.

Comment: @Tony, typo, corrected, thanks. Re classes, it's a whole different kindof mess, with overloaded casting and other operators you can get a whole lot of problems.

Comment: So control will reach "whatever is here" in the following ex code:                                                                   void foo(){return false;)  if (!foo()){//whatever's here}

Comment: No, it won't compile. But if you change `void` to `bool` - then yes.

Comment: Oh yeah. Small error. But the concept of it is correct right?

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will remember to change that return type though

Answer (score 0):

`!` means "logical-not"... it inverts the boolean sense of the following value (i.e. tests the following value is false).  If necessary, the following value will be converted to a boolean first: numeric/pointer values other than `0` are `true`, `0` (NULL) is `false`; classes can provide a conversion operator that will provide either a `bool` or a numeric/pointer type convertible to `bool`.  Standard-compliant compilers even let you write the functionally identical code:

```
if (not xyz...)
```

Comment: So control will reach "whatever is here" in the following ex code:                                                                   void foo(){return false;)  if (!foo()){//whatever's here}